# Is there a way to replace a character from a sentence

Tags: python-3.x

hey there I want to replace all the 'I' and convert them in 'we'

```
n = 'I am good'
print(n)
```

now if I is replaced It should print 'We are good'.

Comment: This might be quite tedious if you are considering English grammar too. Can you provide some more examples?

Comment: Like converting I am going to school to We are going to school

Comment: Python has immutable strings so you can't update the original string but you can definitely create a new one (using `replace()` method).

Comment: @Joe I don't think he's trying to change the grammar. He's just trying to replace a substring with another one.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz the example given switches the first person from singular to plural, with a corresponding change to the verb. Unless the result is intended to be `"We am good"`, a grammatical change is being requested.

Comment: @Joe Yes, my bad. I didn't pay attention to the verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yess you can do It with Replace Method it goes like this

```
n = 'I am good'
m = n.replace("I","We")
print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    old_string = "I am good"
    new_string = old_string.replace("I am", "we are")
    print(new_string)
```